Demand curve estimation using variation over time
I am interested in the price elasticity of demand, i.e., the β in Di=a+β*pi+εi.
Suppose I observe two time periods but different individuals in both years (i.e., I do not have a panel). In t=1, all individuals i face the same constant price: pi,0=p0. In period t=2, individuals face an individual-specific price that follows some pricing rule: pi,1=b+c*X1i,1+d*X2i,1, where X1 and X2 are observable characteristics of i and b,c, and d are constants. Suppose that X1 has n different realisations and X2 has m. Moreover, assume that pi,1 is strictly larger than pi,0 for all i.
I would like to use this variation in prices to identify β. My idea was to group individuals by X1 and X2, such that I have n*m groups and then simply run the standard regression to estimate the demand curve within groups: Di,g=ag+βg*pi,g+εi,g.
My question is whether βg would be identified and how I can derive the average β to draw some aggregate demand curve.

You will need some additional assumptions, but since you have two points on every $Q_g$, you should be able to fit a line between them in principle. This assumes that you have some people in each cell in both periods.
Let individual demand be $$q_{i,t} = \alpha_{g,t} + \beta_{g,t} \cdot p_{g,t} + \varepsilon_{i,t}.$$
Suppose you raise the price tomorrow by $1. Then the change in quantity demanded is
$$q_{i,t+1} - q_{i,t}= (\alpha_{g,t+1} - \alpha_{g,t}) + (\beta_{g,t+1} -  \beta_{g,t}) \cdot p_{g,t} + \beta_{g,t+1} \cdot 1 + (\varepsilon_{i,t+1} - \varepsilon_{it}).$$
The first assumption is that you have coefficient stability over time for each group. This gives you $(\alpha_{g,t+1} - \alpha_{g,t}) = (\beta_{g,t+1} -  \beta_{g,t}) = 0$, so that leaves you with $\beta_g$. I have no idea if that is reasonable here. A year may be a long time for some products. Without that, the price variation is conflated with preferences changing with time.
The second assumption is that the price setter does not know the realized shocks in the second period (or anticipate them) when setting the rule. Without that, he can set high prices for high epsilon groups so that prices will be endogenous and your estimates biased. This eliminates the error term difference in expectation.
The third assumption is that customers cannot fake/choose their type once they observe that the firm price discriminates. This is hard to represent here without complicating notation.
If you estimate the intercepts and slopes jointly for all groups with a customer-level model with group dummies, price, and group x price interactions, it will be easier to sum the coefficients into aggregate demand since you need to weight each group by number of consumers: $Q(p_1,\ldots,p_G)=\sum_{g=1}^{G} (\hat \alpha_g + \hat \beta_g \cdot p_g) \cdot N_g$. You will need some assumptions here about the $N_g$s. You can use the first period, second period, an average of these two, or a forecast. This will make it easier to combine estimates and get the standard error on the total. I would cluster the standard errors by group.

Dear Dimitriy, thanks a lot for your helpful response. The assumptions seem to be reasonable in my case.
